# Advice on Redux State Update and API Call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What is the best way to update my application state, and then make an API call when my application state has updated.

I have an application that makes an API call where I pass in an application level object.

Here is my container method that calls two actions.  The first updates the search criteria that I will then use to make my api call. The problem is that the application state is not updated when I make the fetchActivityData call.

```
//container.js
 clickHandler(){
    this.props.setActivityId(this.props.activity.id); 
    this.props.fetchActivityData(this.props.searchCriteria);
} 

.......

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ setActivityId, fetchActivityData }, 
dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        searchCriteria: state.searchCriteria
    };
}
```

Then I have a bunch action creators for updating my API call criteria

```
//criteria_actions.js
export function setActivityId(activityId){
return {
    type: SET_ACTIVITY_ID,
    payload: activityId
  }
}

export function setSort(sort){
   return {
     type: SET_SORT,
     payload: sort
  }
 }

export function setSortOrder(sortOrder){
    return {
       type: SET_SORT_ORDER,
       payload: sortOrder
   }
 }
```

Here is the criteria action reducer:

```
export default function(state = initialCriteria, action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVITY_ID: {
        return {...state, activityId: action.payload};
    }
    case SET_SORT: {
        return {...state, sort: action.payload};
    }
    case SET_SORT_ORDER: {
        return {...state, sortOrder: action.payload};
    }
    case SET_SEARCH_TERMS: {
        return {...state, searchTerms: action.payload};
    }
    case INCREMENT_PAGE: {
        return {...state, page: state.page+1 };
    }
    case SET_PAGESIZE: {
        return {...state, pagesize: action.payload};
    }
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Then I have an action creator that makes the API call

```
//api_action
export function fetchActivityData(searchCriteria) {
const { activityId, sort, sortOrder, searchTerms, page, pagesize } = searchCriteria;
var otherFilters = "";

if(activityId === 7){
    otherFilters = '"media": "all"';
}

const request = axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${API_ROOT}/activities/campaigns/${PROJECT_ID}/sort/${sort}/sortorder/${sortOrder}/page/${page}/pagesize/${pagesize}/?filter={"at":[${activityId}],"search":"${searchTerms}",${otherFilters}}`,
    headers: {
      "USER_TOKEN": USER_TOKEN,
    }
  });

return {
    type: FETCH_ACTIVITY_DATA,
    payload: request
}
}
```

Here is my API reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_ACTIVITY_DATA:
        return action.payload.data.data.items;
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're omitting the most important aspect of the problem;  How are `setActivityId` and `fetchActivityData` related? You mentioned that `setActivityId` has some impact on the later used input to `fetchActivityData`, but what impact is that?  That's the piece of your code that has the true problem.

Speaking more generally;

Redux actions should reflect an abstract action of the user.  User actions should, ideally, map directly to redux actions.

Actions, themselves, can be very complex though.  Actions can even be composed of other actions, if you wrap them in a function that can be consumed by Redux Thunk.  E.g.;

```
someUserAction(input) {
    return (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(anotherAction(input));
        dispatch(aThirdAction(input));
    }
}
```

This is where it becomes difficult to apply best practices to your case though, without more knowledge.  Based on what info you provided, I would imagine a solution would look something like this:

```
export function setActivityIdAndFetch(activityId){
    return (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(setActivityId(activityId));

        let searchCriteria = //some derived value
        dispatch({
            type: SET_SEARCH_CRITERIA,
            payload: searchCriteria
        });

        dispatch(fetchActivityData(searchCriteria));
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that I would move the searchCriteria set to it's own dispatch.  I suspect you're deriving this value inside of a reducer currently, but that logic ought to exist in the action creator, for exactly these kinds of purposes.

Comment: so essentially I am making an API call to return a filtered collection.  The filters parameters are various hierarchies so I have them separated into different containers.

Each filter container calls an action creator that gets reduced and stored into searchCriteria {}.  Then this object gets passed to the fetchData action.  In your solution, I would need to access the application level state within my action creator in order to access searchCriteria.  How would I do this?

Comment: That's the exact section I had to comment out as `//some derived value`, due to not having the info on your project;  That comment should be replaced by a function that correctly computes the new `searchCriteria` and returns it.  You can get the current value from `getState().searchCriteria` and you already have the activityId, which should be everything needed to compute the new `searchCriteria` value.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!